# Как сделать формулу sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть формула которая подставляет значения из переменных

```
RESULT = 88.36 + (13.4 * WEIGHT) + (4.8 * HEIGHT) - (5.7 * AGE)
```

Мне нужно сделать тоже самое, но значения брать уже из бд, которые там имеются. Я не знаю как это сделать, пробовал получился не рабочий запрос

```
cur.execute(("SELECT 88.36 + (13.4 * weight_column) + (4.8 * height_column) - (5.7 * age_column) as needed_ccal FROM user_info WHERE id_column = ?"), (message.from_user.id,))

result = cur.fetchone()
```

что нужно написать чтобы формула сработала и ответ сохранился в переменной или как поле в бд?

Comment: Какая ошибка?
Какие колонки есть в user_info?

Comment: ошибки не выдает, но ответа я не получаю. Колонки id_column, weight_column, height_column, age_column, gender_column

Comment: Какое значение оказывается в result?  вас лишние скобки. SQL  выражение в данном случае не нужно помещать в них. По хорошему сначала можете напрямую сделать запрос из этой БД и убедиться, что сам запрос работает, что есть нужные данные в БД.

Comment: в result оказывается None, остальное позже проверю